# XPath - how to exclude text from child node

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xml-parsing, tei

I want this output (example):

*I want this*

I'm working with a XML/TEI document and I need to work with XPath expression and I want as output the text in the div/u, but without the text inside node element like "desc" or "vocal><desc" or the text between "anchor/><anchor/" (example).

From the code (example):

```
<div>
<u> 
I want this but 
     *<anchor/><desc>I don't want this</desc><anchor/>
      <anchor/>I don't want this also<anchor/>
     <del type="">I don't want this too</del>*
I want this
</u>
</div>
```

I tried to use (example) :

```
TEI//u[not(desc)]
```

But it excludes every `<u>` with `<desc>` inside.

Comment: Your description is rather confusing, esp. the part about "*the text between "anchor/><anchor/"*". Any text node between the two `anchor`elements in your example would be a child of `u` and would be also selected by `//u/text()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your requirements as:

*select any text node that is a* child *of `u` (i.e. not inside another element such as `desc` or `del`), but exclude text nodes that are in-between two `anchor` elements*

then I arrive at the following expression:

```
//u/text()[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::anchor] and following-sibling::*[1][self::anchor])]
```

Applying it to the given input produces:

```
" 
I want this but 
     **
I want this
"
```

which is different from the output you *say* you want, but nevertheless conforms to the stated requirements.

Answer (score 2):

### Old answer

This XPath,

```
//u/text()
```

will select all text node children of all `u` elements in the document:

```
I want this but 
I want this
```

If you only want the first text node children, use

```
//u/text()[1]
```

Note that this will select first text nodes of *all* `u` elements in the document.  If you only want the first of these text nodes, use

```
(//u/text())[1]
```

---

### Updated answer

Oops, a comment by @y.arazim made me realize that the tags here,

```
<anchor/>I don't want this also<anchor/>
```

despite their positioning, are self-closing, not opening and closing tags around the text.  I wrote the old answer based on that mistake.

See [@y.arazim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78244217/290085) (+1) for an XPath that meets his interpretation of OP's requirements (and properly accounts for the self-closing `anchor` tags).

If OP more simply wants the `u` text node children before or after any `anchor` sibling elements, then this XPath would suffice:

```
//u/text()[not(preceding-sibling::anchor and following-sibling::anchor)]
```

Comment: I suspect this is the right answer (+1), but see my comment to the question.

Comment: The result I get when testing this code `//u/text()` against the given input includes "I don't want this also".

Comment: @y.arazim: You're right.  due to their positioning and my carelessness, I misread the text in `<anchor/>I don't want this also<anchor/>` as being surrounded by opening and closing `anchor` tags, not self-closing tags.  I've added an update (and upvoted your answer) to address your helpful comment.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression will return text of all "u" tags excluding the text of any "desc" or "anchor" tags within them:

```
TEI//u//text()[not(ancestor::desc) and not(ancestor::anchor)]
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! I will applied this method with other similar situation.

Comment: This has quite a few problems:  (1) It selects the text inside `del`, which OP doesn't want. (2) It requires updating for every parent or ancestor that is *not* wanted.  (3) Both `desc` and `anchor` are ancestors to text nodes and so, for the example at least, `not(ancestor::desc)` is redundant.   Consider instead a [simpler approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78238579/290085).